# NLTK TextTiling Error: "No paragraph breaks were found(text too short perhaps?)"

Tags: python, nltk

I wanted to use Python’s TextTiling to split a collection of texts (research papers) into different parts. However, I found that while TextTiling worked fine for some texts, it always reported the following error for some other texts:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9121500407b3> in <module>()
      4         with open(fp) as file_object:
      5             contents=file_object.read()
----> 6             tiles=ttt.tokenize(contents)
      7             filename='e:/collection.txt'
      8             with open(filename,'a') as file_object:

C:\Users\Dennis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\texttiling.pyc in tokenize(self, text)
    111                                 if wi[0] not in self.stopwords]
    112 
--> 113         token_table = self._create_token_table(tokseqs, nopunct_par_breaks)
    114         # End of the Tokenization step
    115 

C:\Users\Dennis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\texttiling.pyc in _create_token_table(self, token_sequences, par_breaks)
    238             except StopIteration:
    239                 raise ValueError(
--> 240                     "No paragraph breaks were found(text too short perhaps?)"
    241                     )
    242         for ts in token_sequences:

ValueError: No paragraph breaks were found(text too short perhaps?)
```

Even though the texts were from different sources and pre-processed by different researchers, I didn’t think they are fundamentally different in length and format.

I doubted that the problem might come from the line breaks in the troubled texts, and added two more carriage returns after each paragraph. This time, TextTiling could work, but the results were not satisfactory since it almost split the texts as their original paragraphs.

My question: Why does this happen? Why does TextTiling report different processing results for two sets of text that seem not to be different?

Comment: paste your code and then we can work from there